# Retrieve Outlook data using Python

Tags: python, macos, email, outlook, reporting

I am part of a start-up, managing customer queries for the company.
Currently am using MSFT Outlook on a Mac for sending and receiving mails, at least until we can get ourselves a proper ticketing tool.

My problem is that i quite often miss out on following up on mails to customers. Also the whole reporting aspect is a nightmare with multiple excel sheets all over the place.

Since all the data is present on my Outlook (i.e. mails sent, responses received, conversations, etc.) was wondering if i could retrieve the data from Outlook itself and set up reporting on that. 
I have been learning a bit of Python have been searching for connecting with Python to Outlook.

i came across the Python + COM bit here: http://www.boddie.org.uk/python/COM.html
But this is specifically for Windows machines.

What would be an alternative for a Mac?

Many Thanks,

The Toing

Answer (score -1):

for email formatting & appended files:

```
import email
```

for sending:

```
import smtplib
```

for receiving:

```
import poplib # or
import imaplib
```

all modules are delivered with python.

you will need to connect to the mail server and find the well done documentation with google.